# not sure about the definition of a macro in a sample of OnLisp

Tags: common-lisp

Here are some sample codes from text of OnLisp.
My question is that why it bothers to use a lambda function,

> `(funcall (alrec ,rec #'(lambda () ,base)) ,@lsts))

as second argument to alrec in the definition of on-cdrs?

What is the difference if I just define it without using lambda?

> `(funcall (alrec ,rec ,base) ,@lsts))

```
(defun lrec (rec &optional base)
  (labels ((self (lst)
             (if (null lst)
                 (if (functionp base)
                     (funcall base)
                   base)
               (funcall rec (car lst)
                        #'(lambda ()
                            (self (cdr lst)))))))
    #'self))


(defmacro alrec (rec &optional base)
  "cltl2 version"
  (let ((gfn (gensym)))
    `(lrec #'(lambda (it ,gfn)
               (symbol-macrolet ((rec (funcall ,gfn)))
                                ,rec))
           ,base)))

(defmacro on-cdrs (rec base &rest lsts)
  `(funcall (alrec ,rec #'(lambda () ,base)) ,@lsts))
```

Comment: The arguments to `lrec` are functions. `alrec` passes its second argument to `lrec`, so it has to be a function.

Comment: @Barmar: Might as well turn your comment into an answer, as it is one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't say how this is intended to be called and this code is a bit of a tangle so at a quick glance I couldn't say how it's supposed to work.  However, I can answer your question.

First, let me say that

```
(if (functionp base) (funcall base) base)
```

is terrible programming style.  This effectively puts a whole in your semantic space, creating a completely different handling of functions as objects than other things as objects.  In Common Lisp, a function is supposed to be an object you can choose to pass around.  If you want to call it, you should do so, but you shouldn't just say to someone "if I give you a function you should call it and otherwise you should not."  (Why this matters will be seen as you read on.)

Second, as Barmar notes, if you write ,base you are basically saying "take the code and insert it for evaluation here".  If you write

```
#'(lambda () ,base)
```

you are saying put the code inside a function so that its execution is delayed.  Now, you're passing it to a function that when it receives the function is going to call it.  And, moreover, calling it will evaluate it in the lexical environment of the caller, and there is no intervening change in dynamic state.  So you'd think this would be the same thing as just evaluating it at the call site (other than just a little more overhead).  However, there is a case where it's different.

If the thing you put in the base argument position is a variable (let's say X) or a number (let's say 3), then you'll either be doing (lrec ... X) or (lrec 3) or else you'll be doing

```
(lrec ... #'(lambda () X))
```

or

```
(lref ... #'(lambda () 3))
```

So far so good.  If it gets to the caller, it's going to say "Oh, you just meant the value of X (or of 3)."  But there's more...

If you say instead an expression that yields a function in the base argument position of your call to on-cdrs or your call to alrec, you're going to get different results depending on whether you wrote ,base or #'(lambda () ,base).  For example, you might have put

```
#'f
```

or

```
#'(lambda () x)
```

or, even worse,

```
#'(lambda (x) x)
```

in the base argument position.  In that case, if you had used ,base, then that expression would be immediately evaluated before passing the argument to lrec, and then lrec would receive a function.  **And then it would be called a second time (which is probably not what the macro user expects unless the documentation is very clear about this inelegance and the user of the macro has cared enough to read the documentation in detail).**  In the first case, it will return 3, in the second case, the value of x, and in the third case an error situation will occur because it will be called with the wrong number of arguments.

If instead you implemented it with

```
#'(lambda () ,base)
```

then lrec will receive as an argument the result of evaluating one of

```
#'(lambda () #'f)
```

or

```
#'(lambda () #'(lambda () 3))
```

or

```
#'(lambda () #'(lambda (x) x))
```

depending on what you gave it as an argument from our examples above.  But in any case what lrec gets is a function of one argument that, when evaluated, will return the result of evaluating its body, that is, will return a function.

The important takeaways are these:

1. The comma is dropping in a piece of evaluable code, and wrapping the comma'd experession with a lambda (or wrapping any expression with a lambda) delays evaluation.
2. The conditional in the lrec definition should either expect that the value is already evaluated or not, and should not take a conditional effect because it can't know whether you already evaluated something based purely on type unless it basically makes a mess of functions as first-class data.

I hope that helps you see the difference. It's subtle, but it's real.

So using

```
#'(lambda () ,base)
```

protects the macro from double-evaluation of a base that might yield a function, but on the other hand the bad style is something that shouldn't (in my view) happen.  My recommendation is to remove the conditional function call to base and make it either always or never call the base as a function. If you make it never call the function, the caller should definitely use ,base.  If you make it always call the function, the caller should definitely include the lambda wrapper.  That would make the number of evaluations deterministic.

Also, as a purely practical matter, I think it's more in the style of Common Lisp just to use ,base and not bother with the closure unless the expression is going to do something more than travel across a function call boundary to be immediately called.  It's a waste of time and effort and perhaps extra consing to have the function where it's really not serving any interesting purpose.  This is especially true if the only purpose of the lrec function is to support this facility. If lrec has an independent reason to have the contract that it does, that's another matter and maybe you'd write your macro to accommodate.

It's more common in a functional language like Scheme, which has a different aesthetic, to have a regular function as an alternative to any macro, and to have that function take such a zero-argument function as an argument just in case some user doesn't like working with macros.  But mostly Common Lisp programmers don't bother, and your question was about Common Lisp, so I've biased the majority of my writing here to that dialect.

Comment: Hi Kent, Really appreciate your detailed explanation. Thank you very much for the effort!